# How can I efficiently optimize the number of coordinates in a 2D path?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, game-development

I'm working with a large number of coordinates in a 2D environment. The coordinates model a path.

Here's an example:

```
path = [(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (3,1), (3,2), (2,2), (1,2), (0,2)]
```

I want to optimize this path by removing the redundant coordinates. Often times the coordinates move along a straight line on either the X or the Y axis. Therefore, all the points in between the "corner" coordinates could be removed from the path.

This path would be equivalent to the one above:

```
path = [(0,0), (3,0), (3,2), (0,2)]
```

Here's an image to describe the desired optimization:

[image: path example]

The coordinates will always line up straight on one of the axis. Diagonal lines can be ignored.

It would be great if someone could give me a hint on how to achieve this in an efficient way. I need to run the optimization algorithm many times since the path is procedurally generated.

Comment: This is essentially the same problem as removing duplicates in a sorted array. Except that instead of removing all duplicates, you want no more than 2 of each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with the following solution: Every time I add a new point to the path, I check  if the X or the Y value equals the values of the two previous points. If this is true, I can remove the middle one of the 3 points.

```cs
private void RedundancyCheck()
{
    if (this.Points.Length < 3)
    {
        return;
    }
    var last = this.Points[this.Points.Length-1];
    var secondLast = this.Points[this.Points.Length-2];
    var thirdLast = this.Points[this.Points.Length-3];

    if ( (last.x == secondLast.x && last.x == thirdLast.x)
        || (last.y == secondLast.y && last.y == thirdLast.y) )
    {
        RemovePoint(this.Points.Length-2);
    }
}
```

This algorithm seems to run quite fast and I was able to reduce the amount of coordinates from ~450'000 to ~3300. (of course this depends on the coordinates)

Answer (score 1):

The [Rahmer-Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) algorithm in many cases is suitable to reduce the number of points along a `2D` route.

**Example in python:**

```
#  pip install rdp

from rdp import rdp

path = [[0,0], [1,0], [2,0], [3,0], [3,1], [3,2], [2,2], [1,2], [0,2]]

rdp(path)

#  output: [[0, 0], [3, 0], [3, 2], [0, 2]]
```

[rdp project home](https://pypi.org/project/rdp/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this algorithm is quite resource intensive and with a worst case complexity of O(n^2) not useful for my case.